# Python3: accessing only unique names of a module as dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, python-import, python-module

I'm writing a text editor.  I have a .py file with a bunch of user scripted commands.  I'd like to get all of the different commands from all of the different files they might be loaded from into a single dictionary.

Calling __dict__ on the module object works great.  Except it gives me *every* name in the module namespace (builtins), which clutters and obfuscates.

Is there an idiomatic way to get only the unique or explicitly defined names from a module object?

Comment: _"I have a .py file with a bunch of user created commands."_ - Instead of cluttering up a whole module with all those user-defined values, use a dictionary to map the user-defined values to a specific key. This allows you to keep your user-defined variables separate from your regular variables.

Comment: The user-defined values are not simply keybindings or configuration variables.  I have actual commands created by the user, Emacs style.  The editor is fully extensible (like, FULLY) through Python scripting, and I'm trying to create a loading feature general enough to handle that. Perhaps I misunderstand you, but I don't see how I can cram actual python code into a dictionary.  New commands for this editor are implemented as class objects with a .execute method - I have actual class definitions in this .py file that I need to import.

Comment: So you are generating and executing _actual_ Python code at runtime?

Comment: I think so?  I have commands defined in .py files.  They work by manipulating methods exposed to them by the core editor objects (Window, Region, etc).  During startup, I want all of the commands (class objects with a .execute classmethod) as the values of a dictionary, with regex objects as the key.  The regex object defines the keybinding, and is used to match keyboard input.  It's a little more complicated than that (some experimental, ambitious ideas in this editor), but basically I just need control over the namespace my imported class definitions wind up in.

Comment: Read about https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#special-attributes